# Making graphics for IOS applications

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, graphics2d

I don't quite understand how to make graphics for IOS. My problem is that I don't know what size to create the image in paint.net. I want my app to be universal. For example I want to create a character at the bottom of the screen, lets say that for the iphone 6. I want the pixel size to be (in portrait mode) 200px by 400 px. I can create that image in paint.net with that size but I also need to create two other images for higher resolutions. What sizes should the other two images be? Am I going about this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, there are 3 sets of images you have to prepare:

- 200 x 400px ( non-retina , name it as **yourimage.png** )
- 400 x 800px ( retina , name it as **yourimage@2x.png** )
- 600 x 1200px ( retina for iPhone 6 Plus , name it as **yourimage@3x.png** )

There are other cases that you might want to take care of, especially background images, launch images as well as app icons.

To manage assets in Xcode, it is suggested to use **Image Assets**, which will advise you which image is missing, and which size is required.

Comment: What happens if there's some new iphone that has a higher resolution that they run my app on, or an older resolution. How will my app look if I only have these three images?

Comment: When there is a new iPhone model with new resolution, you'll have to update your App. But no worry, Apple has no foreseeable schedule of releasing new devices yet, at least not known for now.

Comment: There are already different devices (source: http://iosdesign.ivomynttinen.com/ ) with different pixel sizes other than those three, how does apple warp my images to fit properly on the different device screens? And when I'm placing an image on the screen, should I always be doing it in regard to the screen width and height (so my image locations are a percentage of the width and height)?

Comment: You have to use Auto Layout to decide the position of graphics. Study & try to use it. You'll only need 3 sets of graphics for most of the cases (except background images, launch images and app icons)